# Setting up test environment for SSL torrents using libtorrent and open tracker

Tags: ssl, https, bittorrent, libtorrent

So I am trying to setup a test environment for bittorrent file tranfers with SSL protection and I am having some troubles and would need some guidence.

**My setup:**

**PC1:** Running opentracker and is acting as the Certificate Authority.

**PC2:** Running libtorrent example client compiled with support for SLL encryption. Also acts as the publisher of the torrent file.

**PC3:** Same as PC2 but is not publishing any file.

When I use this setup without SSL torrents everything works as expected. The file gets transferred and if you go into the trackers stats page (trackerip/stats) it shows that 1 torrents is beeing served and there are 2 peers connected.

However, when I use my SSL torrent this is not happening. First of all, no file is being transferred. Second of all the tracker doesn't seem to recognize the torrent file i.e the tracker tells me it is currently not serving any torrents.

What could be wrong with my setup? And how do I start troubleshooting this?
Could it be that the tracker have to support HTTPS? Maybe I can't use open tracker. Do anyone have experience with this?

It is very likely that something is missing in the torrent file, but should I not be getting any errors in that case?

I am using the libtorrent example project "make_torrent" to make my ssl torrent and when I inspect it, it contains my certificate.

EDIT:
So a big part of my problem I assume is that I have zero experience from working with SSL stuff. So this is probably where I fail. I have read through both http://www.libtorrent.org/manual-ref.html#ssl-torrents and http://blog.libtorrent.org/2012/01/bittorrent-over-ssl/
and I am not sure I fully understand it.

I will try to explain how I have interpreted it and you guys can explain why I am wrong :) .

My interpretation:

The publisher of the torrent will include a x509 certificate signed with the publishers private key. 
When a peer receives this torrent it will use the publishers public key (installed at an earlier time) to verify it's authenticity. 
If everything is OK, the peer will generate a Certificate Signing Request and sign it with the peers private key and then send it to the publisher who signs it and returns a certificate. This is then the certificate that the peer will present to other peers.

Is this correct?

Comment: Have you seen [the blog post?](http://blog.libtorrent.org/2012/01/bittorrent-over-ssl/) It has a bit more info than [the manual.](http://libtorrent.org/manual-ref.html#ssl-torrents)

Comment: you may want to print out any alerts you get from libtorrent. Perhaps most interesting would be if you get the torrent_need_cert_alert. Which would indicate you forgot to provide the certificate to the torrent. (every peer needs a certificate signed by the CA to be allowed to join the swarm)

Comment: @Encombe I have read it before, but I am not sure I fully understood it.

Comment: @Arvid I ran the application with logging turned on and it seems like it can't find the correct certificate or something. I have edited my question a bit since I suspect that my problem is more of an overall SSL question.